# Intersection of cell with subcomplex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

if I have a CW-complex $K$ and a subcomplex $L$, what can I say about an $n$-cell $K_{\sigma}$ if its intersection with $L$ is non-empty and not contained in the $(n-1)$-skeleton $K^{(n-1)}$? Does $K_{\sigma}$ have to be in $L$?

I know that then the intersection of $K_{\sigma}$ with $L$ contains an open subset of $K_{\sigma}$. But I don't know if it tells us anything more.

Thank you!

Comment: A CW complex is a set-theoretic disjoint union of its *open* cells. Thus if $(K_\sigma)^\circ$ meets $L$, then $K_\sigma$ belongs to $L$. If $(K_\sigma)^\circ$ does not meet $L$, then it is still possible that $\partial K_\sigma$ meets $L$, but if it does it meets it in $L^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: Thank you @Tyrone !